# **HELP** Calculating mixed fraction in Java Code

Tags: java, arrays, scope, calc

I want to make the calculation of `1_1/2 * 1_1/2`. I couldnt figure our how to do so, but below is my current code, and below that is my thought code for this implementation. I know my code is restricted to a basic num1 op. and num2. I want if num1 or num2 equals 1_1/2 is that 1 would be seems as a whole number and make it 2/2 and it would be added to 1/2 to make 3/2 and do the division to make it 1.5 and follow the equation suit.

```
static int DO_DEBUG = 0;  // set to 1 for messages on, or 0 for messages off

static final boolean BASIC_VERSION = true;


public static void main( String[] args ) {

    calculator();
    //test();
}


public static void test() {
    String[] tests  = { 
            "1+1",
            "12 * 12",
            "1_1/2 * 1_1/2",
            "12 + mom",
            "12/3 / 3",
            "1_/3 + 5",
            "1 & 4",
            "12 +5",
            "1/3 - 1_4/5/6"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( "TESTING: " + tests[i] );
        processInput( tests[i] );
    }

}
static void calculator() {

    Scanner console = new Scanner ( System.in ); //turing input on

    System.out.println();
    String level = "Basic";
    if (! BASIC_VERSION ) {
        level = "Advanced";
    }
    System.out.println( "Welcome to the " + level + " Calculator");// have the option to pick basic or advance

    String input = "";
    while ( true ) {
        printPrompt();//this prompt is introduced in a different method
        input = console.nextLine();
        if ( isQuitRequest( input ) ) {//method to quit, says 'bye'
            break;//ends
        }
        processInput( input );// doing the task
    }
    System.out.println( "bye" );
    System.out.println( );
    console.close(); // quite keyword that closes console
}

static boolean isQuitRequest( String input ) {
    return input.equalsIgnoreCase( "quit" );
}

static void processInput( String input )  {

    if ( isQuitRequest( input ) ) { // if quit, does not reach here
        return;
    }

    String error = null;

    String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
    if ( tokens.length < 3 ) {
        error = "Not enough entires.";
    } else if (tokens.length > 3 ) {
        error = "Too many entries.";
    }
    if (error != null ) {
        printError( input, error );
        return;
    }

    String operator = tokens[1];
    String addition  = "+";
    String subtraction = "-";
    String multiplication = "*";
    String division = "/";
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
    double result;
    String number1 = tokens[0];
    String operation = tokens[1];
    String number2 = tokens[2];
    debug( "processInput: parse result number1='" + number1 + "' "
            + "number2='" + number2 + "' "
            + "operation='" + operation  + "'."
        );

    if ( (! isNumberValid( number1 ) ) 
            || (! isNumberValid( number2 )
            || ( operation.length() != 1 )
            || ("+-*/".indexOf( operation ) < 0 )) ) {
        error = "Syntax error.";
    }
        // If there is an error, print it,
        //  else print the parse results.
    if (error != null ) {
        printError( input, error );
    } else {
        //System.out.println( "Numbers are " + number1 + " and "
            //  + number2 + ".  Operation is " + operation +".");

        if (operator.equals(addition)){
            result = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else if (operator.equals(subtraction)){
            result = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else if (operator.equals(multiplication)){
            result = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else if (operator.equals(division)) {
            result = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else {

        }

            }
    }



//just validating -_-
 static boolean isNumberValid( String  numstr ) {
     boolean isValid = true;
     if ( BASIC_VERSION ) {
         isValid = isValidInt( numstr );
     } else {    // ADVANCED version.
         isValid =  isValidMixedFraction( numstr );;
     }
     return isValid;
 }

//This is to assure that everything entered is valid
 static boolean isValidInt( String  numstr ) {
     boolean isValid = true;
     for( int i = 0; i < numstr.length(); i++ ) {
        char c = numstr.charAt( i );
        if (! Character.isDigit( c )) {
            isValid = false;
        }
     }
     return isValid;
 }


 // formating of mixed numbers
 static boolean isValidMixedFraction( String  numstr ) {
     boolean isvalid = true;

        // get parts this string around the _
     String[] underscoreTokens = numstr.split("_");
     String firstPart = underscoreTokens[0];
     String secondPart;
     if( underscoreTokens.length == 1 ) {
         secondPart = null;
     } else  if( underscoreTokens.length == 2 ) {
         secondPart =  underscoreTokens[1];
     } else {  // underscoreTokens.length > 2 length matters
         return false;
     }


     debug( "isValidMixedFraction:  firstPart='"+ firstPart + "',  secondPart='"
             + secondPart +"'" );        
     if (secondPart == null ) {
         // first part can be "n" or "n/n"
         if( (! isValidInt( firstPart ) ) && (! isValidFraction( firstPart )) ) {
             isvalid = false;
         }
     } else {  // 2nd part not null.

         if  ( ! isValidInt( firstPart ) ) {
             isvalid = false;
         }
         if  ( ! isValidFraction( secondPart ) ) {
             isvalid = false;
         }
     }   // end else second part not null
     return isvalid;
 }

//validating the format of the fraction if it is to be valid
 static boolean isValidFraction( String  numstr ) {
     boolean isValid = true;
        // get parts this string around the _
     String[] slashTokens = numstr.split("/");
     if( slashTokens.length != 2 ) {
        return false;
     }

     String firstPart = slashTokens[0];
     String secondPart = slashTokens[1];

     if ( ! isValidInt(firstPart) ) {
         isValid = false;
     }  else if (! isValidInt(secondPart) ) {
         isValid = false;
     }
     return isValid;
 }


 static void printError( String input, String error ) {
    System.out.println( "ERROR: " + error + "  for input '" + input + "'." );
}

static void printPrompt() {
    System.out.print( "> " );
}

static void debug( String s ) {
    if ( 0 < DO_DEBUG) {
        System.out.println( "DBG: " + s);}
    }

}
```

Other:

```
String num1; 
String num2;

d1 = Double.parse.Double(num 1);
d1 = convtMixed(num1);



double convertMixed(String fract)
double result = 0;
fract.split(_);

result + = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);
```

How? What would you do? Am I using scope right? Where?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, @kickbuttowski. Can you help me out here?

Comment: other person asked you to explain what 1_1/2 means in your code?

Comment: What other person? I know what it means. I just am confused. 1 is a whole number, and that is a part of what was a token before, then _ that is the split that tells that 1/2 is a fraction. I want to convert 1 to 2/2 and add it to 1/2 to be 3/2 and be divided to 1.5 to follow an entered expression suit

Comment: you can separate each operation with operator  what before operator processed and get result then use it in second operation i will provide code for that

Comment: Thanks. At this point, I just want to see how it is all done. (Self-teaching java)

Comment: sorry for late , its simply to check if user enter '(' then first number is the number after this and the number before it store in tempNum , also the operator store in tempOP , make calculation , last thing when use enter ')' we will retrieve tempNum tempOP result in result

Answer (score 0):

Just get idea from this code , your code is wrong sir you will face many trouble so my advise to you change your whole code

*don't use many if , replace it with switch

```
String number1 = tokens[0];
String operation = tokens[1];
String number2 = tokens[2];

if(number2 == '('){
tempNum = number1 ;
tempOP =operation ;

number1 =  tokens[2];
operation = tokens[3];
number2 = tokens[4];
     }

if( tokens[5] == ')'){
number1 = tempNum ;
operation = tempOP ;
number2 = result 

}
```

My Advise to refine your code

```
    String addition  = "+";
    String subtraction = "-";
    String multiplication = "*";
    String division = "/";



 if (operator.equals(addition)){
            result = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else if (operator.equals(subtraction)){
            result = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else if (operator.equals(multiplication)){
            result = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
        else if (operator.equals(division)) {
            result = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + result);          
        }
```

Replace all this code with , (if you have many compares don't use nested if, use switch)

```
  switch (operator) {
    case "+":
         result = num1 + num2;
         System.out.println("Answer is " + result); 
    break;
// other compare here
    default:
        break;
    }


 String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
    if ( tokens.length < 3 ) {
        error = "Not enough entires.";
    } else if (tokens.length > 3 ) {
        error = "Too many entries.";
    }
```

Here you limit your operation with just three element , use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

```
                                              // any input here
StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer("1 / ( 1 / 2 )");
       for(int i = 0 ; i<string.countTokens() ; i++){
           // you can put result in array of string to refer to it alter 
           //String [] result , and fill it with tokens from StringTokenizer 
           String result = string.nextToken();
           if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("(")){
               // write my syntax here 

           }
       }
```

Comment: This just confused me more. How is my code wrong in its entirety?

Comment: @Integral i update my answer , get some idea and try to do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I really hope that you don't need help in parsing equations, just in making whole thing work. If it is true, you may find my answer usefull.

Try to create new class for number. This new class will have two fields:

```
int divisor
int divident
```

Whole numbers would be saved also this way: 1 = 1/1, 2=2/1.

You will have to provide normalise function, funtion that changes 25/5 into 5/1.
This is relatively easy as only thing you have to do is to find gretest common divisors of those numbers and then just divide them.

You will have to override operations like add, multiply, divide, etc. 
For example (pseudocode for addition)

```
Number a;
Number b;
divident = a.divident * b.divident;
divisor = a.divisor * b.divident + b.divisor*a.divident;
normalise();
```

In the and if you want just raw result you can implement function that will simply divide divident and divisor and return result as a double

For example: 1_1/2 using this method will be processed as follows(after parsing):
number a: 1/1
number b: 1/2
action: addition
if addition implemented correctly it will return 3/2 as result.

In model of your application I wouldn't advise changing 3/2 to 1.5 . That kind of more or less one way transformations should be done in wiev part of your application. This way you can be flexible, when it comes to display result. You can give it in any way the user wants, just like in real advanced calculators.

Comment: Very helpful, but my problem was parsing the equation and it being able to do the calculation correctly.